# sql joins needed help further

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I am stuck on a query where I want to display data from different tables and their bridge tables.
The tables are:

```
bridge (bid,planid,fbridgeid)
fbridge (fbridgeid,featureid,valueid)
features (featureid,fname)
value (valueid,value)
plans (planid,name,price,discount)
```

Below is my query so far:

```
SELECT 
(NAME AS pname, price AS prize,
 discount AS ds, fname AS feature, VALUE AS vlue 
FROM plans  )
```

I want to get all the columns from database , but according to the plans

```
like planid 1 ->> contains ->> feature id 1,2,3 and valueid 1,3,5 etc )
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Join`s will be:

```
SELECT pl.name AS pname, pl.price AS prize , pl.discount AS ds , fe.fname AS feature, va.VALUE AS vlue
FROM plans pl
JOIN bridge br ON br.planid = pl.planid
JOIN fbridge fb ON fb.fbridgeid = br.fbridgeid
JOIN features fe ON fe.featureid = fb.featureid
JOIN value va ON va.valueid = fb.valueid
WHERE pl.plainid = 1
```

Comment: Thank very much all the queries work the same .. but the data is being repeated .. i have also used group by                                                                   `SELECT p.name AS pname, p.price AS prize, p.discount AS ds, f.fname AS feature, v.value AS vlue
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN bridge b ON p.planid = b.planid
INNER JOIN fbridge fb ON b.fbridgeid = fb.fbridgeid
INNER JOIN features f ON fb.featureid = f.featureid
INNER JOIN VALUE v ON fb.valueid = v.valueid
GROUP BY pname`

Comment: result : `pname   prize   ds      feature    vlue    
<br/>
medium  30      20      discspace  20gb    
small   20      15      bw         30gb    `

Answer (score 0):

Join your tables on their correct fields.

```
SELECT *
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN bridge b ON p.planid = b.planid
INNER JOIN fbridge fb ON b.fbridgeid = fb.fbridgeid
INNER JOIN features f ON fb.featureid = f.featureid
INNER JOIN value v ON fb.valueid = v.valueid
```

Then you can select any fields from them all.

```
SELECT p.name AS pname, p.price AS prize, p.discount AS ds, f.fname AS feature, v.value AS vlue
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN bridge b ON p.planid = b.planid
INNER JOIN fbridge fb ON b.fbridgeid = fb.fbridgeid
INNER JOIN features f ON fb.featureid = f.featureid
INNER JOIN value v ON fb.valueid = v.valueid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.bid,b.planid,b.fbridgeid,fb.fbridgeid,f.featureid,f.fname,v.valueid,v.value,p.name,p.price,p.discount from bridge as b 
inner join fbridge as fb on fb.bridgeid=b.bridgeid 
inner join features as f on f.featureId=fb.featureid 
inner join value as v on v.valueid=fb.valueid 
inner join plans as p on p.planid=b.planid 
where p.planid=1 and f.featureId in (1,2,3) and v.valueid in (1,3,5)
```

Comment: typo in `inner join fbridgeid as fb`, it should be `inner join fbridge as fb`